# Problema submenú desplegable. (No se mantiene visible)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un menú y una de las opciones tiene un submenú. El submenú quiero que se despliegue cuando paso el ratón por encima del elemento que lo contiene, y lo hace, pero en cuanto intento ir a una de las opciones del submenú, desaparece.

Aquí el código HTML y CSS (Reducido):

```css
<style>

 nav{
  
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 
 .nav{
  
  padding-top: 15px;
 }
 
 .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link{
  
  background-color: red;
 }
 
 .nav-link{
  
  color: red; 
 }
 
  .nav-link:hover {
   
   color: #fff;  
  }
  
  /* Control de los submenús */
     .submenu{
     
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
  }
  
  .mostrar:link ~ .submenu {
   
   display: none;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .mostrar:visited ~ .submenu {
   
   display: none;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .mostrar:focus ~ .submenu {
   
   display: none;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .mostrar:hover ~ .submenu {
      
   display: block;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .mostrar:active ~ .submenu {
   
   display: none;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .menu{
   
   display: block;
  }  
</style>
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" role="tablist">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#inicio" role="tab" aria-controls="inicio" aria-selected="true">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link mostrar" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicios" aria-selected="true">Servicios</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 submenu" role="tablist">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicio1" aria-selected="true">Servicio 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicio2" aria-selected="true">Servicio 2</a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso pasa por que el elemento que debe tener el `hover` es el padre directo del menú desplegable y no su hermano (en este caso la etiqueta `<a>`).

Cuando estás intentando salir de la etiqueta `<a>` para ingresar al menú desplegable estás terminando la ejecución del `hover` y es por eso que se vuelve a desaparecer, mientras que si su elemento padre fuera el que tuviera el `hover` sin importar si estas encima de la `<a>` o del menú desplegable vas a seguir estando en el elemento que tiene el `hover`.

Espero haber sido claro, si tienes dudas con gusto las responderé.

```css
nav{ 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link{
    background-color: red;
}

.nav-link{
    color: red; 
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;        
}

/* Control de los submenús */
.submenu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.mostrar:hover > .submenu {        
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" role="tablist">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#inicio" role="tab" aria-controls="inicio" aria-selected="true">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mostrar">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicios" aria-selected="true">Servicios</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 submenu" role="tablist">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicio1" aria-selected="true">Servicio 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="servicio2" aria-selected="true">Servicio 2</a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```